# Probability by using Bayes formula

Tags: probability, bayesian

We have installed an alarm at home. At burglary it makes noise by 96% certainty, but also on other nights it can make noise at probability of 0.3% due to disturbances. In our neighborhood there is a burglary chance of 3% on any given night in a given home. Tonight the alarm makes noise, how likely is it that there really is a burglary?
I solved it this way, can someone check if i have something wrong.
Let B the even that there is a burglary and A that alarm makes noise.

$P(A \mid B) = 0.96,\\ P(B) = 0.03,\\ P(B^C) = (1-0.03)$

$P(A \mid B^C) = 0.003$

$P(B \mid A) = ? ==>$ $\frac{P(A \mid B)P(B)}{P(A \mid B)P(B) + P(A \mid B^C)P(B^C)}$

is this right way or i make mistakes?

Comment: please add self study tag

Comment: this looks right

Comment: "In our neighborhood there is a burglary chance of 3% on any given night in a given home." - maybe you should move. :)